# How to download a tcl file

Tags: wget

I'm very new to Ubuntu server and I'm just experimenting with IRC eggdrop bots. I would like to download a TCL file from http://www.egghelp.org/tclhtml/3478-4-0-31-1.htm
I know that wget is the command to download something from a website but every time I try to use wget with the specific URL I can't get the file I want. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

All `tcl` files are zipped on that page and downloads are http redirect. So for example, i'm going to download `!Ping` TCL from this page: http://www.egghelp.org/tclhtml/3478-4-0-0-1.htm using `wget`

First, I copied the link address by right clicking on `!Ping` link and then:

```
wget -O Ping.zip "http://www.egghelp.org/cgi-bin/tcl_archive.tcl?mode=download&id=1175"
```

hope this help.

see `man wget` for more wget help.